# Multiple Facebook buttons on the same page

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to use multiple facebook like buttons on the same page but sharing different data.

I know i can set the og:image, og:title dynamic with the following code

```
jQuery('.item-facebook').hover(function()
    {
        var image_url = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.item-left .photo-url').attr('src');
        jQuery('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content', image_url);       
    });
```

But when i hover the button the opengraph tags are updated in the page but the iframe is allready loaded.

Does anybody know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you click the like button, Facebook issues a HTTP request to the page the user has liked from the Facebook servers, and looks for the Open Graph tags in the header without executing Javascript. You can get an idea of how it works by using the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

As a workaround, you could have multiple like buttons with different a different `href` that would point to the same page, but with different Open Graph tags.

Comment: Tnx for you answer. I have used the debugger function but i can't replicate it because the hover function will modify the open graph clientside. And how can i do the same with different description tags?